# Языковой вопрос (Глазарий языка)

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Перед вами три слова. Первое было заимствовано финским языком из русского. Второе и третье — соответственно японским и испанским языками из английского. Что, с точки зрения фонетического оформления в языке-преемнике, их объединяет?
raamattu (финск.), miruku (японск.), estandar (испанск.)

Этот вопрос был задан на Глазарий языка. Ответа я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти слова объединяет [элизия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)):

финск. raamattu ("библия") и эст. raamat ("книга") => русское "грамота" (элизия  начального согласного)

японское ミルク [miruku] => англ. milk ("молоко"); слог ル [ru] также произносится с элизией (редуцированное неслоговое у; элизия безударной моры)

испанское estándar => английское standard (элизия конечного согласного).